# How can I set a script to run a newline is added to the end of a file?

Tags: bash

I have a file called `alarm.log`, and I want a script to automatically run when this file is changed.

Comment: your-script < tail -f alarm.log

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `inotify`, specifically `inotyfywait` (man page **[here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)**).

Basic usage:

```
while inotifywait -e modify alarm.log; do <myScript>; done
```

There are plenty of good examples of usage in **[this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)**.

Comment: I have a file script who ping host and when to someone host has packet lost write in log file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running systemd, check out [systemd.path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) . Systemd path units use `inotify` internally, but by using a systemd unit you get a service that is running in the background independently of your login session.